# Attaching file to node field

Tags: 7, nodes, entities, files

I have a problem. I'm trying to attach file to node field by this code

```
function calculator_page_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
$file = file_save_upload('file', array(
    // Validate extensions.
    'file_validate_extensions' => array(),
    ));
    // If the file passed validation:
    if ($file) 
    {
            // Move the file into the Drupal file system.
            if ($file = file_move($file, 'public://cunning_files', FILE_EXISTS_RENAME)) {
            // Save the file for use in the submit handler.
            $form_state['storage']['file'] = $file;
        }
        else 
        {
            form_set_error('file', t("Failed to write the uploaded file to the site's file folder."));
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        form_set_error('file', t('No file was uploaded.'));
    }
}
function calculator_page_form_submit($form, &$form_state) 
    {
        $file = $form_state['storage']['file'];
        // We are done with the file, remove it from storage.
        unset($form_state['storage']['file']);
        // Make the storage of the file permanent.
        $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
        // Save file status.
        file_save($file);
        $file->display = 1;
        $file->description = "";
        // Set a response to the user.
        drupal_set_message(t('The form has been submitted and the image has been saved, filename: @filename.', array('@filename' => $file->filename)));
        global $user;
        $node = new stdClass();
        $node->title = $file->filename;
        $node->type = "file";
        //node_object_prepare($node); // Sets some defaults. Invokes hook_prepare() and hook_node_prepare().
        $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE; // Or e.g. 'en' if locale is enabled
        $node->uid = $user->uid;
        $node->status = 1; //(1 or 0): published or not
        $node->promote = 0; //(1 or 0): promoted to front page
        $node->comment = 0; // 0 = comments disabled, 1 = read only, 2 = read/write
        // Term reference (taxonomy) field
        //$node->field_tag[$node->language][]['tag'] = $form_state['values']['tag'];
        add_terms_for_node($form_state['values']['tag'], &$node);
        $file->display = 1;
        $file->description = "";
        $node->field_file[$node->language][0] = (array)$file;
        // 'node' is default,
        // Other possible values are "user" and  "taxonomy_term" 
        $node = node_submit($node); // Prepare node for saving
        node_save($node);
        //drupal_set_message( "Node with nid " . $node->nid . " saved!\n");
    }
```

What am i doing wrong? Thank you for help and sorry for my poor engrich it isn't my natural language.

Comment: Maybe you could try to stick to Drupal's coding standards https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/standards. It helps keeping code readable very well.

Answer (score 1):

I found mistake. I accidently named field_file as field_fiele. Damn it four houers from life. Code works correctly.